# Find Average, MaxValue and MinValue and the Corresponding DateTime that the Values occur

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I am working on a SQL query where I have to find out Average, Max value, Max Value-DateTime, Min Value, Min Value-DateTime of each Group of any Date. For this I used following query

```
SELECT
    Dl.TagDescID,
    convert( decimal(18,2), AVG( Dl.Value ) ) AS 'TotalAvgValue',
    convert(decimal(18,2), MAX( Dl.Value ) ) AS 'MaxValue',
    MAX( Dl.Date ) MaxDate,
    convert( decimal(18,2), MIN( Dl.Value ) ) AS 'MinValue',
    Min( Dl.Date ) MinDate
FROM
    tblDataLog AS Dl WITH (nolock) 
    INNER JOIN tblTagDescription AS TD WITH (nolock) ON Dl.TagDescID = TD.ID 
WHERE
    ( CONVERT(date, Dl.Date, 103) = CONVERT(date, @StartDate, 103) )
    AND
    ( TD.GroupName = @Group )
GROUP BY
    Dl.TagDescID
`

     TagDescID  TotalAvgValue   MaxValue    MaxDate MinValue    MinDate
       1    36.59   36.59   2020-01-07 10:13:42.293 36.59   2020-01-07 10:13:32.750
       2    20.49   20.49   2020-01-07 10:13:42.293 20.49   2020-01-07 10:13:32.750

In the above Data Set The MaxValue of TagDescID 1 is 36.59 and its Date as 'MaxDate' should be the exact datetime when this maxvalue Arrives in the table tblDataLog. here Max-Date of MaxValue of TagDescID 1 is '2020-01-07 10:13:42.293' but the value should have been '2020-01-07 08:13:42.293'. Same for MinValue and MinDate For each TagDescID.

How to solve it?
```

Comment: you should include a summary dataset and result set that shows what you were expecting and the actual observed result

Comment: So you want to filter by `Date` but also return the `Max(Date)` and `Min(Date)` I think we're missing something here, if we filter on Date, then Max and Min will be the same value... Or are you looking for the Max and Min time for the specified day?

Comment: I want Average value, MaxValue, MaxValue DateTime, MinValue, MinValue DateTime of each TagDescID of any Date

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected results - thats the only way to clearly communicate exactly what you are looking for. Also you should certainly avoid using `with (nolock)` unless its absolutely necessary

Comment: You shouldn't use `CONVERT( date, Dl.Date, 103 )` because it isn't a SARGable predicate. Why isn't `@StartDate` a `date` value already? What is the actual datatype of `Dl.Date` in the `CREATE TABLE` statement?

Comment: Please do not post image. Post the sample data and expected result as text

Comment: You say `MaxDate and MinDate should be the Datetime when the MaxValue or MinValue inserted`, but what if there are multiple entries for the same date with the same value? do you want the first one, last one or both?

Comment: For MaxDate it should be Last one but for MinDate it should be first one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are really asking for multiple aggregate and grouping sets at the same time. What you are observing is that each *column aggregate* expression is returning the result of that aggregate independently of the other columns, this is by design.

> In the above query `MaxDate` and `MinDate` should be the *Datetime* when the `MaxValue` or `MinValue` inserted to the table `tblDataLog`.

In SQL Server we have a number of ways to query this.

One way is to query the set for the Max and Min values, then re-query the set for the Max and Min Dates around those times.

> In this example I'm using a CTE instead of a simple nested query because I find the syntax more readable.
>
> > The two `CROSS APPLY` queries will evaluate *once* for each result in the `Daily` CTE.
> >     This solution can be more efficient to using an inline lookup for the `DateTime` of the corresponding log records because it doesn't have to lookup once for every row in `tblDataLog`, this solution will result in 2 additional lookups for every row that is returned by the group by.

```sql
;WITH Daily as
(
    SELECT  
        Dl.TagDescID, 
        convert(decimal(18,2),AVG(Dl.Value)) AS [TotalAvgValue],
        convert(decimal(18,2),MAX(Dl.Value)) AS [MaxValue], 
        convert(decimal(18,2),MIN(Dl.Value)) AS [MinValue] 
    FROM @tblDataLog AS Dl  
    INNER JOIN @tblTagDescription AS TD ON Dl.TagDescID = TD.ID 
    WHERE (CONVERT(date, Dl.Date, 103) = CONVERT(date, @StartDate, 103)) AND (TD.GroupName=@Group) 
    GROUP BY Dl.TagDescID  
)
SELECT Daily.TagDescID, TotalAvgValue, MaxValue, [Max].Date MaxDate, MinValue, [Min].Date MinDate
FROM Daily
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(DlMax.Date) Date FROM @tblDataLog DlMax WHERE DlMax.TagDescID = Daily.TagDescId AND (CONVERT(date, DlMax.Date, 103) = CONVERT(date, @StartDate, 103)) AND DlMax.Value = Daily.MaxValue) as [Max]
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(DlMin.Date) Date FROM @tblDataLog DlMin WHERE DlMin.TagDescID = Daily.TagDescId AND (CONVERT(date, DlMin.Date, 103) = CONVERT(date, @StartDate, 103)) AND DlMin.Value = Daily.MinValue) as [Min]
```

Another way to do this is to group by the date, instead of filtering for an explicit date value, so this will summarize by date and tag, giving you a report across multiple dates and multiple tags if you want it:

```sql
;WITH Daily as
(
    SELECT  
        Dl.TagDescID, 
        TD.GroupName,
        CONVERT(date, Dl.Date, 103) as Date,
        MAX(Dl.Date) as Max_Date,
        MIN(Dl.Date) as Min_Date,
        convert(decimal(18,2),AVG(Dl.Value)) AS [TotalAvgValue],
        convert(decimal(18,2),MAX(Dl.Value)) AS [MaxValue], 
        convert(decimal(18,2),MIN(Dl.Value)) AS [MinValue] 
    FROM @tblDataLog AS Dl  
    INNER JOIN @tblTagDescription AS TD ON Dl.TagDescID = TD.ID 
    GROUP BY Dl.TagDescID, TD.GroupName, CONVERT(date, Dl.Date, 103)
)
SELECT Daily.Date, Daily.GroupName, Daily.TagDescID, TotalAvgValue, MaxValue, [Max].Date MaxDate, MinValue, [Min].Date MinDate
FROM Daily
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MAX(DlMax.Date) Date FROM @tblDataLog DlMax WHERE DlMax.TagDescID = Daily.TagDescId AND DlMax.Date >= Daily.Min_Date AND DlMax.Date <= Daily.Max_Date) [Max]
CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(DlMin.Date) Date FROM @tblDataLog DlMin WHERE DlMin.TagDescID = Daily.TagDescId AND DlMin.Date >= Daily.Min_Date AND DlMin.Date <= Daily.Max_Date) [Min]
-- Optional Date Filter
-- WHERE TD.GroupName=@Group AND Daily.Date = @StartDate
```

In my test set, this returns:

```
Date        GroupName   TagDescID   TotalAvgValue   MaxValue    MaxDate                      MinValue   MinDate
2020-03-11  Test        1           5.00            8.00        2020-03-11  22:00:00.000     2.00       2020-03-11 10:00:00.000
2020-03-15  Test        1           5.00            8.00        2020-03-15  13:00:00.000     2.00       2020-03-15 06:00:00.000
```

> Un-comment the `where` clause to enable your date filter, or you could change it to a date range and you would still see results by day.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are after. The corresponding `Date` when `Value` is minimum and maximum. You can use a `sub-query` to do this

```
SELECT
    Dl.TagDescID,
    convert( decimal(18,2), AVG( Dl.Value ) ) AS 'TotalAvgValue',
    convert(decimal(18,2), MAX( Dl.Value ) ) AS 'MaxValue',
    --MAX( Dl.Date ) MaxDate,
    (SELECT TOP 1 x.[Date] FROM  tblDataLog x WHERE x.TagDescID = Dl.TagDescID ORDER BY Value DESC) As MaxDate,
    convert( decimal(18,2), MIN( Dl.Value ) ) AS 'MinValue',
    --Min( Dl.Date ) MinDate
    (SELECT TOP 1 x.[Date] FROM  tblDataLog x WHERE x.TagDescID = Dl.TagDescID ORDER BY Value) As MinDate
FROM
    tblDataLog AS Dl WITH (nolock) 
    INNER JOIN tblTagDescription AS TD WITH (nolock) ON Dl.TagDescID = TD.ID 
WHERE
    ( CONVERT(date, Dl.Date, 103) = CONVERT(date, @StartDate, 103) )
    AND
    ( TD.GroupName = @Group )
GROUP BY
    Dl.TagDescID
```

EDIT : as others commented, avoid `CONVERT(date, Dl.Date, 103) = CONVERT(date, @StartDate, 103)`

You can replace that with

```
WHERE Dl.Date >= @StartDate
AND   Dl.Date <  DATEADD (DAY, 1, @StartDate)
```

Comment: The above query is showing wrong Max-Date and Min-Time. I am searching for 7 jan 20 and it is showing of 3 jan 2020 and 06 jan 2020.

Comment: if you can provide some sample data that will be great. As of now, we are purely guessing on your requirement